# RSpec feature specs can't find routes for Rails Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails, rails-engines

I'm developing a Rails Engine using `rails v5.1.0` and `rspec-rails 3.5.2`.

I have a simple feature spec:

```
require "rails_helper"

module MyEngineName
  RSpec.feature "Some Feature", type: :feature do
    it "user can navigate to page and blah blah", :js do
      visit edit_job_path(1)
      # .... other stuff
    end
  end
end
```

This raises the error

```
undefined method `edit_job_path' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::SomeFeature:0x007fc098a570e8>
```

because the route helper `edit_job_path` can not be found.

Is there something special I need to do in order to allow my feature specs to access my engine routes?

The RSpec documentation [mentions that you can specify the engine routes](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/routing-specs/engine-routes), but that only appears to be for routing specs. When I added it to the feature specs, it fails with `undefined method 'routes'`

Thanks!

**EDIT:** Since my routes file was requested, adding it here. It's pretty short -

```
# config/routes.rb
MyEngineName::Engine.routes.draw do
  root to: redirect("/my_engine_name/jobs")
  resources :jobs
end
```

List of all routes from rake

```
> rake app:routes
   ....
   ....

Routes for MyEngineName::Engine:
    root GET    /                        redirect(301, /my_engine_name/jobs)
    jobs GET    /jobs(.:format)          my_engine_name/jobs#index
         POST   /jobs(.:format)          my_engine_name/jobs#create
 new_job GET    /jobs/new(.:format)      my_engine_name/jobs#new
edit_job GET    /jobs/:id/edit(.:format) my_engine_name/jobs#edit
     job GET    /jobs/:id(.:format)      my_engine_name/jobs#show
         PATCH  /jobs/:id(.:format)      my_engine_name/jobs#update
         PUT    /jobs/:id(.:format)      my_engine_name/jobs#update
         DELETE /jobs/:id(.:format)      my_engine_name/jobs#destroy
```

Comment: @chumakoff - Edited the post with it. Thanks!

Comment: @chumakoff, did u managed it somehow?

Answer (score 3):

For API request specs, I tried both ways but it doesn't work

```
routes { MyEngine::Engine.routes }
```

and

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before :each, type: :request do
    helper.class.include MyEngine::Engine.routes.url_helpers
  end
end
```

**If the above solutions doesn't work**, **try loading helper urls as rspec configs as below:**

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include MyEngine::Engine.routes.url_helpers
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Something from this should help. Make sure that you have `MyEngineName::Engine.routes`, not `MyEngineName.routes`

```
require "rails_helper"

module MyEngineName
  RSpec.feature "Some Feature", type: :feature do
    routes { MyEngineName::Engine.routes }

    it "user can navigate to page and blah blah", :js do
    # ...
```

or (another solution)

```
# place this in `spec/rails_helper.rb` file
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before :each, type: :feature do
    helper.class.include MyEngineName::Engine.routes.url_helpers
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! The first approach throws an error - `undefined method 'routes' for RSpec::ExampleGroups::SomeFeature:Class (NoMethodError)` - as I don't think `routes` is a valid method definition (not sure why?). The second shows some promise, as it definitely was able to recognize `edit_job_path`! But it threw an error in trying to load the assets for that page - `No route matches [GET] "/assets/my_engine_name/application-(fingerprint).js"`. That *kinda* makes since that route is not defined by route helpers right? I also have no idea why it's fingerprinting assets in `test` environment... Thanks!

Comment: @user2490003 `routes { MyEngine::Engine.routes }` only works if your spec has `type: :controller` in its definition. For example: `Rspec.describe MyEngine::FooController, type: :controller`.